# Randomization generates the same initial value

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to develop a quiz app which generates unpredictable questions on android studio using kotlin programming language and i already know that to generate a random number, the following code is used:

object.text = Random. nextInt(lower value..upper value)

Now, i am surprised that every time i open the app, the first number generated between 1 and 10 is always 6 and i don't want that to be the case. In Visual Basic 6, putting "randomize" before the randomization code solves the problem but i don't know what does the same for kotlin and i have searched through the internet but no luck. Any help on this?

Comment: Kotlin's default random generator should already produce unique values - you have to call `Random(seedValue)` to create a generator that produces the same sequence every time. So you don't need to explicitly randomise it, that's the default behaviour: https://pl.kotl.in/7qyVbB90L (run that a few times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 1.3 version, Kotlin comes with its own random generator. This extension function is now part of the Kotlin standard library, use it like:

```
val randomNumber = (1..10).random() // generated random number from 1 to 10 included
```